# Queries written inside Oracle Package/Procedure/Trigger/Functions

Tags: oracle, plsql, data-dictionary

I want to fetch all the queries (Select queries) that has been written inside Oracle PLSQL Package/Procedure/Functions/Triggers. My question is are those queries retained somewhere in Oracle when those Packages/Procedures etc are executed, like in DBA_HIST% tables or v$SQL/SQLAREA/SQLTEXT tables. If not, is there any way I can fetch them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Oracle data dictionary view [ALL_SOURCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2063.htm#i1588578) ?

Answer (score 1):

From 12.2 onwards, [PL/Scope](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/plscope-12cr2) can collect details of SQL statements within stored PL/SQL.

If you compile one or more (or all) PL/SQL program units with (for example):

```
alter session set plscope_settings='STATEMENTS:ALL';

call dbms_utility.compile_schema(user);
```

then the SQL statements will appear in the [USER|ALL|DBA_STATEMENTS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/ALL_STATEMENTS.html) views:

```
select type, object_name, object_type, line, sql_id, text
from   user_statements;
```

| TYPE | OBJECT_NAME | OBJECT_TYPE | LINE | SQL_ID | TEXT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INSERT | ADD_JOB_HISTORY | PROCEDURE | 10 | 252ppswgq6pwn | INSERT INTO JOB_HISTORY (EMPLOYEE_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID) VALUES(:B5 , :B4 , :B3 , :B2 , :B1 ) |